# How to get a ggplot2 function of discrete geom_rect to obey the alpha (transparency) values

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, polar-coordinates

I have just ask and answered a question that I need some more help with. Here is the link:
[How to gradient fill an annotation shape in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122423/how-to-gradient-fill-an-annotation-shape-in-ggplot2)

My problem is that for the code I have generated, the geom_rect are not obeying the alpha parameters. The gradient is too dark. Here is the plot with an alpha of 0.15 and no gradient applied: 
[image: alpha = 0.15]

Here is the new plot that has gradient rectangles (the highest alpha was set to 0.1), clearly it is darker than 0.15: [image: alpha set to 0.1]

I have included my code below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or if there is some function that is overriding the alpha parameters for the geom_rect. Additionally, I get one set of errors:

"Warning messages:
1: Removed 50 rows containing missing values (geom_rect). 
2: Removed 50 rows containing missing values (geom_rect). 
3: Removed 50 rows containing missing values (geom_rect). 
4: Removed 50 rows containing missing values (geom_rect). 
5: Removed 50 rows containing missing values (geom_rect). "

I recognize that the error message may be pertaining to the fact that some of the lighter geom_rects were removed for some reason, but I am unsure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #Generate a similar dataset to the one I am working with.   
 library(lubridate);library(ggplot2);library(extrafont);library(openair)
    NoOfHours <- as.numeric(ymd_hms("2019-6-1 00:00:00") - ymd_hms("2018-3-1 00:00:00"))*24 
    data1 <- as.data.frame(ymd_hms("2018-3-01 8:00:00") + hours(0:NoOfHours))
    colnames(data1) <- 'date' 
    set.seed(10)
    data1$level <- runif(nrow(data1), min = 0, max = 400)

    Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(data1$date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")
    data1$hours <- Hours

    Date <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(data1$date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    data1$date_date <- Date#output

    month <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(data1$date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%m-%d")
    data1$month<- month
    start <- ceiling_date(ymd(data1$date_date[1]), "day", change_on_boundary = FALSE)
    startdate <- as.Date(start) %m+% days(1)
    enddate1 <- as.Date(startdate) %m+% years(1)
    enddate<- as.Date(enddate1) %m-% days(1)
    yeardata <- selectByDate(data1, start = startdate, end = enddate, year = 2018:2019) #select for a defined set of years
    graphlimit <- 400
    graphlength <- graphlimit/(1350/1750)
    innerlimit <- -(graphlength*(200/1750))
    plotlimit <- graphlength+innerlimit 
    starttimedate <- ymd_hms(paste(startdate, "01:00:00"))
    endtimedate <- ymd_hms(paste(enddate1, "01:00:00"))

#This section helps determine the rotation of the geom jitter to align January 1 at 00:00:00 at the top  
    NoOfhours <- as.numeric(ymd_hms(starttimedate) - ymd_hms("2018-01-01 00:00:00"))*24
    NoOfHours <- (8760/12)*(month(startdate)-1)
    NoOfHoursall <- as.numeric(ymd_hms(endtimedate) - ymd_hms(starttimedate))*24
    date_vals <- seq(from = ceiling_date(ymd(startdate), "month", change_on_boundary = FALSE), length.out = 12, by = "months")
    finalcell <- length(yeardata$date)

#Dataframes to encompass the seasons.   
    spring <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
      spring$seasonstartdate <- ((yeardata$date[1]))
      spring$seasonenddates <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2018-6-1")))])
      spring$colour <- "springgreen4"
       summer <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
       summer$seasonstartdate <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2018-6-1")))])
        summer$seasonenddates <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2018-9-1")))])
        summer$colour <- "goldenrod2"
        fall <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
       fall$seasonstartdate <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2018-9-1")))])
        fall$seasonenddates <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2018-12-1")))])
        fall$colour <- "orangered3"
         winter <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
         winter$seasonstartdate <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2018-12-1")))])
        winter$seasonenddates <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2019-3-1")))])
        winter$colour <- "orangered3"
          spring1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
      spring1$seasonstartdate <- (yeardata$date[min(which(yeardata$date_date == ymd("2019-3-1")))])
      spring1$seasonenddates <- (yeardata$date[finalcell])
      spring1$colour <- "springgreen4"
  #This function enables geom rectangles to be gradient filled, independently of a gradient fill within a plot.
      ggplot_grad_rects <- function(n, ymin, ymax) {
      y_steps <- seq(from = ymin, to = ymax, length.out = n + 1)
      alpha_steps <- seq(from = 0, to = 0.2, length.out = n)
      rect_grad <- data.frame(ymin = y_steps[-(n + 1)], 
                              ymax = y_steps[-1], 
                              alpha = alpha_steps)
      rect_total <- merge(spring, rect_grad)
      rect_total2 <- merge(summer, rect_grad)
      rect_total3 <- merge(fall, rect_grad)
      rect_total4 <- merge(winter, rect_grad)
      rect_total5 <- merge(spring1, rect_grad)
        ggplot(yeardata)+
                 geom_rect(data=rect_total, 
                  aes(xmin=(seasonstartdate), xmax=(seasonenddates),
                      ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
                      alpha=alpha), fill="springgreen4") +
                 geom_rect(data=rect_total2, 
                  aes(xmin=(seasonstartdate), xmax=(seasonenddates),
                      ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
                      alpha=alpha), fill="goldenrod2") +
                 geom_rect(data=rect_total3, 
                  aes(xmin=(seasonstartdate), xmax=(seasonenddates),
                      ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
                      alpha=alpha), fill="orangered3") +
                 geom_rect(data=rect_total4, 
                  aes(xmin=(seasonstartdate), xmax=(seasonenddates),
                      ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
                      alpha=alpha), fill="cornflowerblue") +
                 geom_rect(data=rect_total5, 
                  aes(xmin=(seasonstartdate), xmax=(seasonenddates),
                      ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, 
                      alpha=alpha), fill="springgreen4") +
        guides(alpha = FALSE)
    }

    plot <- ggplot_grad_rects(100, graphlimit, graphlength) +

      scale_colour_gradientn(limits = c(0,1000), colours = c("grey","yellow","orangered1","red","red4","black"), values = c(0,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.8,1), breaks = c(0, 100, 200, 500, 800, 1000), oob = scales::squish, name = expression(atop("",atop(textstyle("Level"^2*"")))))+ 
        geom_jitter(aes(x=date, y=level, color = level), alpha = 0.2, size = 1) +
     theme(text = element_text(family="Calibri"),  axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))+
       labs(x = NULL, y = bquote('Level'))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, graphlimit, 200),
                         limits = c(innerlimit,plotlimit))+
      scale_alpha_identity() + 
      coord_polar(start = ((2*NoOfhours/NoOfHoursall)*pi))+
      theme(legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), panel.grid  = element_blank())
    plot
```

Now with this fix incorporated: [image: fixed gradient geom rect]

Comment: Can you please try to make this into a minimal reproducible example? This code is very long, which makes it hard to hone in on your actual question.

Comment: Sorry, I will make that code smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a `scale_alpha_identity` or `scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 0.2))`, so I suspect `ggplot` is mapping your various alpha values to the default range of `(0.1, 1)`, regardless of the range of the underlying values.

Here's a short example:

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
my_data <- tibble(
  date = seq.Date(ymd(20190101), ymd(20191231), by = "5 day"),
  month = month(date),
  color = case_when(month <= 2 ~ "cornflowerblue",
                    month <= 5 ~ "springgreen4",
                    month <= 8 ~ "goldenrod2",
                    month <= 11 ~ "orangered3",
                    TRUE ~ "cornflowerblue")) 


my_data %>%
  uncount(20, .id = "row") %>%
  mutate(alpha_val = row / max(row) * 0.2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, 5 + alpha_val * 5, fill = color, alpha = alpha_val)) +
  geom_tile(color = NA) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it was something simple. 'scale_alpha_identity()' worked perfecly. Thanks Again!