# How to fade out geom_rect on both left and right sides in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, linear-gradients

Here is the code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 100, xmax = 105), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.5) +
  xlim(80, 120) +
  theme_bw()
```

I want both sides (left & right) of the rectangular to fade out to transparent. However, current examples only did one side (right or bottom etc.).

For example:

[Fade side of panel to indicate ongoing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082084/fade-side-of-panel-to-indicate-ongoing-time)

[How can I apply a gradient fill to a geom_rect object in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728082/how-can-i-apply-a-gradient-fill-to-a-geom-rect-object-in-ggplot2)

So I'm wondering how to do both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
xmin <- 95
xmax <- 105
xmid <- (xmin + xmax) / 2

n <- 20 # number of steps in gradient, increase to have smoother fading out
alphas <- seq(0,1,1/n)
inc <- (xmid - xmin) / n

xcur <- xmin
df <- NULL
for (alpha in alphas) { # gradient left to right
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(xmin=xcur, xmax=xcur+inc, alpha=alpha))
  xcur <- xcur + inc
}
for (alpha in rev(alphas)) { # gradient right to left
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(xmin=xcur, xmax=xcur+inc, alpha=alpha))
  xcur <- xcur + inc
}

ggplot(df) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, alpha = alpha), 
                     ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "red" 
                     ) + xlim(90, 110) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but the shading is inclusive of the upper limit integer numeric value, so in this case reaching up to 106 instead of 105. Use `alphas <- seq(0,1,1/(n-1))` to fix that.