# Add horizontal gradient fill to geom_tile in ggplot geom_sf map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm making a map and want to add rectangles with a horizontal color gradient (darkest color on the left, fading to white on the right). I initially made the rectangles with `geom_rect` the most similar examples I could find in [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069660/r-gradient-fill-for-geom-rect-in-ggplot2) was using `geom_tile` with a variable `fill`. I tried that below by generating a dummy column `newcol` that just holds the difference between the `xmax` and `xmin` of the real data so that the fill gradient would vary from left to right in each rectangle, but as you can see below, the rectangles still don't have a gradient. Any ideas?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

states <- ne_states(country = c("United States of America","Canada"), returnclass = "sf")

rectangles <- data_frame(
  y = (35:44)+0.5, 
  xmin = c(-75.5, -75.770333, -75.683333, -75.916667, -74.613, -74.0315, 
           -71.916667, -70.666667, -70.466667, -68.4), 
  xmax = c(-74.8, -74.616667, -73.983333, -72.8, -69.216667, -66.416667, 
           -65.65, -65.675833, -66.516667, -66.721667)
)%>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(xmax, xmin), names_to="identity", values_to="x") %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(meanx = mean(x),
         newcol = x - min(x)) 

ggplot(data = states) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_tile(data = rectangles, aes(x=meanx, y=y, width=2, height=1, fill=newcol), color="black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="darkblue", high="white") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-80, -65), ylim = c(34, 45.5), expand = FALSE) +
  NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Dataframe `rectangles` has two values for every x/y position, the latter of which is always zero, so your color scale ranges from 0 to 0. Perhaps you meant `newcol = meanx - min(x)` instead of `newcol = x - min(x)`? Or do you actually want to have *each* rectangle filled with a gradient, then you could try ggpattern: https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern//

Comment: Why would the color scale range from 0 to 0 if there are two different x values for each y? I'm trying to get the fill to vary over those two x-values (which is shown in the color bar on the right of the map, just not in the rectangle fill itself).

Comment: Because `scale_fill_*` doesn't have a gradient option for rectangles (or other polygons at that). The latter of any two rectangles per x/y position overplots the earlier one with a fill of high = low = zero (check df "rectangles"). The legend, on the other hand, duly displays the range of values across all rectangles. If you do need a gradient per rectangle, this should be (only) possible with {ggpattern}.

Comment: I did find this example (now linked in the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069660/r-gradient-fill-for-geom-rect-in-ggplot2) using `scale_fill_*` with `geom_tile` so I think it should be possible without `ggpattern`?

Comment: This example does not show a tile with a gradient fill. It does show a series of stacked narrow tiles, each with a slightly different but uniform fill, mimicking a  gradient. To reproduce that effect, you need to create a series of adjacent west-to-east tiles, group them by y-position and *calculate* a separate west-east colour gradient per group. Aside: be aware of redundant visuals (here: longitude as position *and* color); https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk